# autossh mac cli wont login

Tags: macos, ssh

I tryed to autossh into another machine from my mac cli.
With ssh `ssh <user>@<ip-adress>` I can login into that machine. But when I use `autossh <user>@<ip-adress>` it will only print.

```
usage: autossh [-V] [-M monitor_port[:echo_port]] [-f] [SSH_OPTIONS]

-M specifies monitor port. May be overridden by environment
   variable AUTOSSH_PORT. 0 turns monitoring loop off.
   Alternatively, a port for an echo service on the remote
   machine may be specified. (Normally port 7.)
-f run in background (autossh handles this, and does not
   pass it to ssh.)
-V print autossh version and exit.

Environment variables are:
    AUTOSSH_GATETIME    - how long must an ssh session be established
                          before we decide it really was established
                          (in seconds). Default is 30 seconds; use of -f
                          flag sets this to 0.
    AUTOSSH_LOGFILE     - file to log to (default is to use the syslog
                          facility)
    AUTOSSH_LOGLEVEL    - level of log verbosity
    AUTOSSH_MAXLIFETIME - set the maximum time to live (seconds)
    AUTOSSH_MAXSTART    - max times to restart (default is no limit)
    AUTOSSH_MESSAGE     - message to append to echo string (max 64 bytes)
    AUTOSSH_PATH        - path to ssh if not default
    AUTOSSH_PIDFILE     - write pid to this file
    AUTOSSH_POLL        - how often to check the connection (seconds)
    AUTOSSH_FIRST_POLL  - time before first connection check (seconds)
    AUTOSSH_PORT        - port to use for monitor connection
    AUTOSSH_DEBUG       - turn logging to maximum verbosity and log to
                          stderr
```

When I installed autossh on that other machine I can autossh into my mac.

Is there something wrong with the mac installation? I installed it via brew.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This solution will fix the problem. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/342441/autossh-l-fails-with-same-command-as-ssh-how-to-make-it-work

One have to you use the monitor option `autossh -M 0 <user>@<ip-adress>`.